# React Js data Mapping

Tags: reactjs

Hello i've been trying to map this however i keep getting the error : Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
[image]

this is the code i'm using to fetch the data

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
const [filters, setFilters] = useState(data);

  const getProduct = async () => {
const response = await fetch(Data source (cant share it));
if(componentMounted){
  setData(await response.clone().json());
  setFilters(await response.json());
}

return () => {
  componentMounted = false;
}
}

useEffect(() => {
  getProduct()
   // eslint-disable-next-line
}, [])
```

and this is how i'm mapping the data:

```
     {filters?.list.filter((product) => product.id === id).map((product) => (
          <div className='product-bigger-wrapper'>
          
            <div class="product-list-wrapper"> 
              <div className="product-detail-container">              
                <div>                    
                  <div className="image-container">
                    <img src={product.image} className="product-detail-image" alt=""/>
                  </div>            
                </div> .... }
```

Please Note that everything worked fine before adding the count and the list to the api

Comment: On initial load, `filters` is set to `data`, and `data` is `[]`. At which point `filters?.list` is `undefined`, because the `?.` only checks `filters` is defined (which it is, as an empty array that doesn't have a `.list` property) You might want to check that `.list` is defined as well (`filters?.list?.filter()`)

Answer (score 1):

You've initialized `data` as an array, but you're expecting an object.

It's probably best to set the default value to `undefined`, `null`, or a default object.

```js
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

or

```js
const [data, setData] = useState(null);
```

or

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({count: 0, list: []});
```